# I want to test if add, remove, contains and the iterator of a binary search tree are working

Tags: java, algorithm, unit-testing, binary-search-tree

i got this code that implements a simple binary tree which have methods for adding, removing and searching nodes, also i have an iterator that goes thru nodes. I want to write a test program to test this classes/methods but i don`t know how. Please help if you can :)

```
import java.util.*;

public class BinarySearchTree<T> extends AbstractSet<T> {
    private Node<T> root;
    private int size;

    private static class Node<T> {
        private T element;
        private Node<T> left = null;
        private Node<T> right = null;
        private Node<T> parent;

        private Node(T element, Node<T> parent) {
            this.element = element;
            this.parent = parent;
        }
    }

    public BinarySearchTree() {
        root = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    public BinarySearchTree(BinarySearchTree<T> other) {
        root = null;
        size = 0;
        for (T element: other)
            add(element);
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new TreeIterator();
    }

    public boolean add(T element) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new Node<T>(element, null);
            size++;
            return true;
        } else {
            Node temp = root;
            int comp;
            while (true) {
                comp = ((Comparable)(element)).compareTo(temp.element);
                if (comp == 0)
                    return false;
                if (comp<0) {
                    if (temp.left != null)
                        temp = temp.left;
                    else {
                        temp.left = new Node<T>(element, temp);
                        size++;
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (temp.right != null)
                        temp = temp.right;
                    else {
                        temp.right = new Node<T>(element, temp);
                        size++;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean remove(Object obj)
    {
    Node<T> e = getNode(obj);
    if (e == null)
        return false;
    deleteNode(e);
    return true;
    }

    private Node<T> getNode(Object obj)
    {
    int comp;
    Node<T> e = root;
    while (e != null) {
        comp = ((Comparable)(obj)).compareTo(e.element);
        if (comp == 0)
        return e;
        else if (comp < 0)
        e = e.left;
        else
        e = e.right;
    }
    return null;
    }

    public T mapAdd(T obj)
    {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node<T>(obj, null);
        size++;
        return root.element;
    }
    int comp;
    Node<T> e = root;
    Node<T> p = null;
    boolean left = true;
    while (e != null) {
        p = e;
        comp = ((Comparable)(obj)).compareTo(e.element);
        if (comp == 0)
        return e.element;
        else if (comp < 0) {
        left = true;
        e = e.left;
        } else {
        e = e.right;
        left = false;
        }
    }
    e = new Node<T>(obj, p);
    if (left)
        p.left = e;
    else
        p.right = e;
    size++;
    return e.element;
    }




    public boolean contains(Object obj)
    {
    return getNode(obj) != null;
    }

    private Node<T> deleteNode(Node<T> p)
    {
    size--;
    if (p.left != null && p.right != null) {
        Node<T> s = successor(p);
        p.element = s.element;
        p = s;
    }

    Node<T> replacement;
    if (p.left != null)
        replacement = p.left;
    else
        replacement = p.right;

    if (replacement != null) {
        replacement.parent = p.parent;
        if (p.parent == null)
        root = replacement;
        else if (p == p.parent.left)
        p.parent.left = replacement;
        else
        p.parent.right = replacement;
    } else if (p.parent == null) {
        root = null;
    } else {
        if (p == p.parent.left)
        p.parent.left = null;
        else
        p.parent.right = null;
    }
    return p;
    }

    private Node<T> successor(Node<T> e)
    {
    if (e == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (e.right != null) {
        Node<T> p = e.right;
        while (p.left != null)
        p = p.left;
        return p;
    } else {
        Node<T> p = e.parent;
        Node<T> child = e;
        while (p != null && child == p.right) {
        child = p;
        p = p.parent;
        }
        return p;
    }
    }

    private class TreeIterator implements Iterator<T>
    {
    private Node<T> lastReturned = null;
    private Node<T> next;

    private TreeIterator()
    {
        next = root;
        if (next != null)
        while (next.left != null)
            next = next.left;
    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return next != null;
    }

    public T next()
    {
        if (next == null)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
        lastReturned = next;
        next = successor(next);
        return lastReturned.element;
    }

    public void remove()
    {
        if (lastReturned == null)
        throw new IllegalStateException();
        if (lastReturned.left != null && lastReturned.right != null)
        next = lastReturned;
        deleteNode(lastReturned);
        lastReturned = null;
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Since you already used the tag "unit-testing" you might want to put that into a search engine, probably along with the "java" tag. Then select one of the frameworks that are suggested (JUnit and TestNG are probably at the top), read the documentation (to "know how"), build your tests and run them.

Comment: Yea, just a missclick  :D

Comment: The thing is that i have no experience with testing and an example for this simple algorithm will make a huge difference for me

Comment: There's not much to it. You basically create a test class with test methods as required by the framework you're using (for one-time tests you could even use a main-method) and then you build your tests. In those you'd most probably create a tree with different input (think of common and edge cases), do operations on the tree and check whether the results are as expected - e.g. let's say I'd build a tree from A, C, B I'd expect a binary search for B to be successful but not for D and the structure would be such that A < B < C (possibly with C at the root if the tree is meant to be balanced).

Answer (score 0):

You need to test that the class complies with its contract. So a good starting point is to write down that contract. For example: removing from an empty tree should throw an exception, if I add an element to the tree, contains returns true for that element etc. This can be directly translated into test cases:

- create an empty tree, call remove -> throws an exception (or returns null? what is your contract there?)
- create an empty tree, add an element, check size == 1, check contains returns true, check iterator hasNext returns true, check that iterator next returns the element you added etc.
- create a tree with N elements, check size, check iterator, check that remove changes size to N-1 and that removed element is not in the tree any longer

etc.

Answer (score 0):

To get you starting here a test for the method `contains` when the `tree` does contain the element:

```
@Test
public void containsWhenElementIsPresent() {
    String element = "StackOverflow";
    BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree<>();
    tree.add(new String(element));
    assertThat(tree.contains(element), is(true));
}
```

And here one when the `tree` does not contain the element:

```
@Test
public void containsWhenElementIsAbsent() {
    String element = "StackOverflow";
    assertThat(new BinarySearchTree<>().contains(element), is(false));
}
```

Good luck with all the other tests. And by the way: I used *JUnit 4* and *Hamcrest*.

Comment: I`m using eclipse as my work environement, can i use JUnit there?

Comment: Sure. Eclipse has support for running `JUnit` tests and showing their results.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think your question was better without the code. It is far too big to be able to make sense without actually running it (or writing unit tests for it).

So how to write unit tests for a binary tree (or any other type of tree actually)?

First of all: Unit tests means initializing your tree to a known state performing an operation and then checking that the test tree is the same as the expected result tree.
E.g. if we start with an empty tree and add node "a" we expect the result to be a tree with a single node "a".

To do this test we need two facilities:

1 - A way to easily load the tree.
2 - A way to easily compare the tree to an expected result.

One common and efficient way to do this is with a string representation of the tree. I gather from your code that the tree is not just a binary tree but a binary search tree so using depth-first search (DFS) is a natural way to get a representation of the tree.

Your tests now look:

1. Load the tree from a string where each letter represents a node.
2. Perform the load operation.
3. Use DFS to get a string representation of the tree, add a '|' every time you go back a level.
4. Compare against a string representation of the expected tree.

E.g. to test insertion:

Test 1 - Empty tree
1. Do nothing (empty tree)
2. Insert "a"
3. Save tree to string
4. Assert saved string is equal to "a|".

Test 2 - Left Leaf

1. Load tree "b"
2. Insert "a"
3. Save tree to string
4. Assert saved string is equal to "a|b|".

Test 3 - Right Leaf

1. Load tree "ba"
2. Insert "c"
3. Save tree to string
4. Assert saved string is equal to "a|bc||".

Hope this helps.